# Why is my IPYNB file opened as IPY File in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook file with IPYNB, which when I tried to open in Visual Studio Code, would display an `IPY` extension and no longer in Jupyter Notebook format, but looks like this:
[image]

Why is this happening and how can I convert it to Jupyter Notebook format?

Comment: Do you have the notebook plugin installed?

Comment: Hi @HristoIliev I think so, I have no problem opening other IPYNB files with VSC but just this one.

Comment: Well the code you show looks to be `.ipynb`-based and not `.ipy`-based. `.ipy` code is basically Python with IPython magics allowed. What you show is fragment of json that is generally the underlying code of an `.ipynb` file. I would suggest opening it as a text file like you show in your image and copy it into a new file that you save specifically with an `.ipynb` extenstion. They try opening the new file. Hopefully it opens as a notebook and you can swap out the weird one.

Comment: If that doesn't work. I'd suggest doing the same thing inside a temorary Jupyter session served via MyBinder.org. To do that go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press `launch binder`. After the session spins up, you'll have modern JupyterLab interface. Under `File` select `New` > `Text file` and paste in the text you have. Rename the file by right-clicking on the file name tab and change the extension to `.ipynb`. Try to double-click on that in the file navigator pane on the left & see if it opens as a notebook now. If it does, download that file back to your local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the file type manually.

[image]

Use "F2" and change `.ipy` to `.ipynb`

[image]